# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException in mybatis

Tags: mybatis

###### The phenomenon and background of the problem encountered

Problems encountered when configuring mybatis and writing tests, an error will be reported as soon as you click to run

###### problem related code,

```java
 @Test
    public  void findmany() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream is= Resources.getResourceAsStream("mybatis-config.xml");
        SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(is);
        SqlSession sqlSession =sqlSessionFactory.openSession();


        Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", "sam");
        params.put("major", "");

        List<Student> student=sqlSession.selectList("com.javaee.pojo.Student.findmany",params);
        System.out.println(student);

        Map<String,Object> params2 = new HashMap<>();
        params2.put("name", "");
        params2.put("major", "math");

        student=sqlSession.selectList("com.javaee.pojo.Student.findmany",params2);
        System.out.println(student);

        Map<String,Object> params3 = new HashMap<>();
        params3.put("name", "");
        params3.put("major", "");

        student=sqlSession.selectList("com.javaee.pojo.Student.findmany",params3);
        System.out.println(student);

        sqlSession.close();
    }
```

mapper

```xml
    <select id="findmany"
            parameterType="map"
            resultType="com.javaee.pojo.Student">

        select * from students where name like concat('%',#{name},'%')  major like concat('%',#{major},'%')

    </select>
```

Student Class

```java
public class Student {
    private int id;        
    private String name;    
    private String major;    
    private String sno;       

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Student{"+"id="+id+",sno='"+sno+'\''+",name='"+name+'\''+",major='"+major+'\''+'}';



    }
```

###### Running results and error content

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG8kN.png)

Answer (score 1):

Missing an `AND` in your select, try this way:

```
select * from students where name like concat('%',#{name},'%') AND major like concat('%',#{major},'%')
```